# How to achieve the python solution of given screnario

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is the input dataframe:

```
   ETL_ID  Name          Age    City                 Salary         Score   Address
0     1    John           28    New York --> Jersy   2000 --> 2001  90     I-1
1     2    Alice   25 --> 27    Los Angeles          3500           85     J-2
2     3    Bob     30 --> 31    Chicago              4000           68     K-3
3     4    Alan    33 --> 33.5  Ohio                 2500           92 --> 82  L-9
4     5    David   43 --> 42    D.C.                 5501 --> 5500  88     D-1
```

Here is the output dataframe:

```
  ETL_ID     Age            City                   Score
0    1        28            New York --> Jersy     90
1    2        25 --> 27     Los Angeles            85
3    4        33 --> 33.5   Ohio                   92 --> 82
```

Actually, I need to drop all the columns (except primary key which is ETL_ID in this example) from data frame which does not contain "-->" sign and also, I need to drop all the rows where absolute differences are <=1 (between 2 integer value after split by '-->') in all the columns (which contain -->) else not. What is the python code of above scenario?

1. Exclude ETL_ID
2. Drop all such columns which does not contain '-->' in any value of that particular column
   (Now Name and Address column will be dropped)
3. Drop all such numeric columns where '-->' exist but the absolute split difference is <=1 wherever '-->' exist (eg is Salary)
   (Now Salary column is dropped)
   (And the column remains are ETL_ID, Age City, Score)
4. Drop all such rows where absolute split difference is <=1 from numeric columns
   (Now the entire row of index 2, 4 will get drop)
   Hence the remaining index would remain 0,1 and 3 (this is what is expected)
   Hope I am clear, Thanks!

Below code tried but it seems incomplete

```
for col in df.columns:
    # Drop columns that do not contain '-->' sign
    if not df[col].str.contains('-->').any():
        df = df.drop(col, axis=1)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Drop rows where absolute difference <= 1 for integer columns
    for col in df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns:
        if '-->' in row[col]:
            values = row[col].split('-->')
            if len(values) == 2:
                old_value = pd.to_numeric(values[0].strip(), errors='coerce')
                new_value = pd.to_numeric(values[1].strip(), errors='coerce')
                if abs(old_value - new_value) <= 1:
                    df = df.drop(index)
```

Comment: Can you give us the input you used for your example in code? your example input is confusing, i'm not even sure if your input is a table or a string.

Comment: data = {'ETL_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Alan', 'David'],
        'Age': ['28', '25 --> 27', '30 --> 31', '33 --> 33.5', '43 --> 42'],
        'City': ['New York --> New Jersy', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Ohio', 'D.C'],
        'Salary': ['2000 --> 2001', '3500', '4000', '2500', '5501 --> 5500'],
        'Score': ['90', '85', '68', '92 --> 82', 88],
        'Address': ['I-1', 'J-2', 'K-3', 'L-9', 'D-1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You were really close to the answer, i just changed a few things and it worked as espected:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ETL_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Alan', 'David'], 'Age': ['28', '25 --> 27', '30 --> 31', '33 --> 33.5', '43 --> 42'], 'City': ['New York --> New Jersy', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Ohio', 'D.C'], 'Salary': ['2000 --> 2001', '3500', '4000', '2500', '5501 --> 5500'], 'Score': ['90', '85', '68', '92 --> 82', 88], 'Address': ['I-1', 'J-2', 'K-3', 'L-9', 'D-1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for col in df.columns:
    # Drop columns that do not contain '-->' sign
    df[col] = df[col].apply(str)
    if col!=list(df.columns)[0] and not df[col].str.contains('-->').any():
      df = df.drop(col, axis=1)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Drop rows where absolute difference <= 1 for integer columns
    for col in df.columns:
        if '-->' in row[col]:
            values = row[col].split('-->')
            if values[0].strip().isalpha() == values[1].strip().isalpha() == False and len(values) == 2:
                old_value = pd.to_numeric(values[0].strip(), errors='coerce')
                new_value = pd.to_numeric(values[1].strip(), errors='coerce')
                if abs(old_value - new_value) <= 1:
                    df = df.drop(index)
                    index -= 1;
                    break;
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ETL_ID        Age         City Salary Score
1      2  25 --> 27  Los Angeles   3500    85
```

Answer (score 0):

- First we select all string columns that at least contain the '-->' value and keep them (ETL_ID is not string)
- Then for the string columns we split by the '-->' check if the size is larger than one and we check if the left and right values are numeric.
- Then get the rows to keep for that column based on the criteria below
- This will keep only 1 and 3. 0 is not included because of the salary column as its difference in values is 1.

```py
cols_to_keep = [col for col in df.select_dtypes('object')
                if df[col].str.contains('-->').any()]

df = df[cols_to_keep]

rows_to_keep = pd.Series(True, index=df.index, dtype='bool')

for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    split = df[col].str.split('-->').map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x])
    len_split = split.map(len)
    has_numbers = split.map(lambda x: all([i.isnumeric() for i in x]))
    y = df.loc[(len_split > 1) & has_numbers, col]
    y = y.str.split('-->').map(lambda x: abs(float(x[1].strip())-float(x[0].strip())) > 1.0)
    rows_to_keep[(len_split > 1) & has_numbers] = y & rows_to_keep[(len_split > 1) & has_numbers]

df = df[rows_to_keep]

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Eyad
1. Exclude ETL_ID
2. Drop all such columns which does not contain '-->' in any value of that particular column 
(Now Name and Address colum will be dropped)
3. Drop all such numeric columns where '-->' exist but the absolute split difference is <=1 (eg is Salary)
(Now Salary column is dropped) 
(And the column remains are ETL_ID, Age City, Score)
4. Drop all such rows where absolute split difference is <=1 from numeric columns
(Now the entire row of index 2, 4 will get drop)
Hence the remaining index would remain 0,1, 3 (this is what is expected)
Hope I am clear, Thanks!

Comment: I think 0  should be removed because of the salary difference is less than one